# Access development server - Django

Tags: python, django, redis

I tried to run a friend's Django project on my Ubuntu Virtual Machine but I can't access the development server. 
After a:

```
python manage.py runserver 0:80 --settings=a.settings.dev_a
```

Here the result :

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 19, 2017 - 21:56:31
Django version 1.11, using settings 'a.settings.dev_a'
Starting Channels development server at http://0:80/
Channel layer default (asgi_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer)
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Comment: Try `python manage.py runserver  --settings=a.settings.dev_a` and your server should run at `localhost:8000`

Comment: already done but like i said it doesn't works

Comment: Where did you see that syntax? `0` isn't a valid IP address. Try `0.0.0.0:80` instead. And are you running as root? Normal users can't bind to ports 1024 or lower.

Comment: As mentioned above, try `python manage.py runserver 0:8000` and access at `http://localhost:8000` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. You can also try binding to all of your VMs ports with `python manage.py runserver [::]:8000` if the `0:8000` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 'localhost' to ALLOWED_HOSTS in your "dev_a" file

and then like said @FlipperPA, try a

```
python manage.py runserver [::]:8000 --settings=a.settings.dev_a
```